# How to read .sh_history from thousand of users?

Tags: command-line, scripts

The logic applies to many other objectives. 
And how to read .sh_history of each user from /home/ filesystem? What if there are thousand of them?

Answer (score 0):

This is Hard. You will have to interpret each user's `~/.bashrc`, and all the "Startup Files" for each and every shell to see what "the history file" really is.

For example, mine sets my history file to `~/.history/history.$$`, and I currently have 1372 `.history` files.

My `~/.bashrc` fragment:

```
[[ -d ~/.history ]] || mkdir --mode=0700 ~/.history
[[ -d ~/.history ]] && chmod 0700 ~/.history
HISTFILE=~/.history/history.$$
# close any old history file by zeroing HISTFILESIZE  
HISTFILESIZE=0  
# then set HISTFILESIZE to a large value
HISTFILESIZE=4096  
HISTSIZE=4096
```

Other users may do other things, may call their `.history` files something else, use other shells, ...

Comment: So you have a separate history file for each shell invocation? Interesting idea. I cannot think of a usecase _for me_ but I'm pretty sure you have one.

Comment: @PerlDuck From deleted self-answer posted by OP it is worth mentioning this question is about Korn Shell (`#!/bin/ksh`) not Bash Shell (`#!/bin/bash`). Korn Shell has different history file issues.